# write procedure to go through all letters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to write a procedure which will run the same command but will need to change the LIKE field. It will start at 'aa%' then go to 'ab%' all the way to 'az%. then it will start over with 'ba%', 'bb%' and so on until 'zz%'. I tried running it in a loop but don't know where to get the letters from.

```
SELECT t1.colA, t2.colA, count(*)
FROM (SELECT colA FROM table WHERE colA LIKE "a[a-z]%") t1
JOIN table t2
ON t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colA
HAVING count(*) > 10
INSERT INTO /tmp/[a[a-z]].csv
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

After 26 iterations of that the next would be

```
 SELECT t1.colA, t2.colA, count(*)
    FROM (SELECT colA FROM table WHERE colA LIKE "b[a-z]%") t1
    JOIN table t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date
    GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colA
    HAVING count(*) > 10
    INSERT INTO /tmp/[b[a-z]].csv
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Next would be

```
SELECT t1.colA, t2.colA, count(*)
FROM (SELECT colA FROM table WHERE colA LIKE "c[a-z]%") t1
JOIN table t2
ON t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colA
HAVING count(*) > 10
INSERT INTO /tmp/[c[a-z]].csv
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

and so on until

```
SELECT t1.colA, t2.colA, count(*)
FROM (SELECT colA FROM table WHERE colA LIKE "z[a-z]%") t1
JOIN table t2
ON t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY t1.colA, t2.colA
HAVING count(*) > 10
INSERT INTO /tmp/[z[a-z]].csv
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: why not `like "[a-z][a-z]%"`? and `GROUP BY left(ColA,1), right(left(ColA,2),1)`

Comment: I am not sure you mean exactly?

Comment: add some data sample and desired output and I'll show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a REPEAT. ASCII code values for characters 'a' thru 'z' are 97 thru 122, we can use the `CHAR()` function to return character for a given ASCII code value.

For example:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i = 97;
    REPEAT
        SET c = CHAR(i);

        -- SELECT c;

        SET i = i + 1;
    UNTIL i > 122 END REPEAT;
END
```